# How to capture value of dropdown(on webpage) in sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a dropdown(say department) on the sharepoint home page. The user selects a value from that drop down and then a link to fill a pdf form appears. I am writing a approval workflow which will be initiated when this form will be saved in a sharepoint library.

The workflow will be initiated on the event of saving the form but my problem is how to capture the value of the dropdown which was on the home page.

Any pointer regarding this issue will be of great help .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try sending request parameter like your_infopath_url/template.xsn?department=Finance 
And inside the Form Load event parse the request parameter.

Comment: I tried 
    if CurentItem:EncodedAbsoluteURL contains "Finance"
It is working like this but is there any inbuilt function in SP Workflow to capture the value of QueryString(as we do in ASP.net)